# Generate every possible capitalization of a String

Tags: ruby, string

Given an arbitrary input string, how can I generate a sequence of every possible capitalization its characters?

E.g. given the input `"abc"`, the expected output would be a sequence of these 8 strings:

- `ABC`
- `ABc`
- `AbC`
- `Abc`
- `aBC`
- `aBc`
- `abC`
- `abc`

Answer (score 2):

```rb
# Returns an enumerator that yields every possible capitalization of the input string
# @param [String] input
# @return [Enumerator::Lazy]
def all_possible_capitalizations(input)
  chars = input.downcase.chars

  [true, false]
    .repeated_permutation(chars.count)
    .lazy
    .map do |permutation|
      permutation
        .zip(chars)
        .map { |should_capitalize, char| should_capitalize ? char.upcase : char }
        .join
    end
end

all_possible_capitalizations("abc").each do |s|
  puts s
end
```

You can use `Array#repeated_permutation` on `[false, true]` create an enumerator that yields every possible bit string with a given length, such as:

1. `[true, true, true]`
2. `[true, true, false]`
3. `[true, false, true]`
4. `[true, false, false]`
5. `[false, true, true]`
6. `[false, true, false]`
7. `[false, false, true]`
8. `[false, false, false]`

You can zip each of these with the characters of the input:

1. `[[true, "a"], [true, "b"], [true, "c"]]`
2. `[[true, "a"], [true, "b"], [false, "c"]]`
3. `[[true, "a"], [false, "b"], [true, "c"]]`
4. `[[true, "a"], [false, "b"], [false, "c"]]`
5. `[[false, "a"], [true, "b"], [true, "c"]]`
6. `[[false, "a"], [true, "b"], [false, "c"]]`
7. `[[false, "a"], [false, "b"], [true, "c"]]`
8. `[[false, "a"], [false, "b"], [false, "c"]]`

You can then map over each of these pairs, and use the boolean from the permutation to decide weather to capitalize the paired character, giving you:

1. `["A", "B", "C"]`
2. `["A", "B", "c"]`
3. `["A", "b", "C"]`
4. `["A", "b", "c"]`
5. `["a", "B", "C"]`
6. `["a", "B", "c"]`
7. `["a", "b", "C"]`
8. `["a", "b", "c"]`

Then you just `join` each of the results, to turn the arrays of characters into strings.

Comment: You can use also do Array#repeated_permutation(input.size) on [:upcase, :downcase ], zip the permutations with the chars and `char.send(a_case)` etc.

Comment: Ooo, that's an interesting approach too, I guess it replaces the conditional statement in the middle of middle `map`.

Comment: The lazy seems redundant or am I missing something? Ran your example without it and it seems to work

Comment: @JoelBlum That's kind of the point, `lazy` doesn't change the result values, it just makes it so that they're not all held simultaneously in memory (which doesn't matter for a few-char-long strings like this, but would be an issue for longer ones).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a 1-liner solution. Can possibly be cleaned up somehow, but it's just something I came up with quickly:

```
def all_possible_capitalisations(string)
  string
    .chars
    .map { |char| [char, char.swapcase] }
    .inject { |acc, chars| chars.flat_map { |char| acc.zip([char] * acc.count)} }
    .map(&:join)
end

all_possible_capitalisations("abc")
  # => ["abc", "Abc", "aBc", "ABc", "abC", "AbC", "aBC", "ABC"]
```

How does it work? Let's use a slightly larger example of `"abcd"` to demonstrate it fully... The first step is quite simple; we split the string into pairs of upper- and lower-case characters:

```
[["a", "A"], ["b", "B"], ["c", "C"], ["d", "D"]]
```

Next, comes the magic. Note that:

```
["a", "A"].zip(["b", "b"]) == [["a", "b"], ["A", "b"]]
["a", "A"].zip(["B", "B"]) == [["a", "B"], ["A", "B"]]
```

So, we can start building the list of all possibilities by merging (zipping) together each element of each array, with the current result:

```
["b", "B"].flat_map { |char| ["a", "A"].zip([char, char])}
  # => [["a", "b"], ["A", "b"], ["a", "B"], ["A", "B"]]
```

But note that I "cheated" here a little, and wrote `[char, char]`. Actually, this input needs to be *the same length as the current result*. Combine this information together, and you get the above mentioned `inject` method:

```
inject { |acc, chars| chars.flat_map { |char| acc.zip([char] * acc.count)} }
```

Let's see what happens if we run this whole method *without* the final `.map(&:join)`:

```
  "abcd"
    .chars
    .map { |char| [char, char.swapcase] }
    .inject { |acc, chars| chars.flat_map { |char| acc.zip([char] * acc.count)} }

  # => [
    [[["a", "b"], "c"], "d"],
    [[["A", "b"], "c"], "d"],
    [[["a", "B"], "c"], "d"],
    [[["A", "B"], "c"], "d"],
    [[["a", "b"], "C"], "d"],
    [[["A", "b"], "C"], "d"],
    [[["a", "B"], "C"], "d"],
    [[["A", "B"], "C"], "d"],
    [[["a", "b"], "c"], "D"],
    [[["A", "b"], "c"], "D"],
    [[["a", "B"], "c"], "D"],
    [[["A", "B"], "c"], "D"],
    [[["a", "b"], "C"], "D"],
    [[["A", "b"], "C"], "D"],
    [[["a", "B"], "C"], "D"],
    [[["A", "B"], "C"], "D"]
  ]
```

And there you have it! `join` it all together, and you get a nice simple string again.

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for taking the time to contribute this. I've read it over like 3 times but I still don't get it lol. I'll go re-caffeinate and see if that helps :p

Comment: Actually, here's a slight change that gets the **same result** but might hopefully make the calculation process a little easier to comprehend: Move the `.map(&:join)` to just after the `acc.zip([char] * acc.count)`, instead of putting it at the end.

Comment: I understand all the pieces (inject/reduce, zip, etc.), just the way they're put together just didn't "click" yet

Comment: Suppose you had a "partial result" of some arbitrary length, e.g. `acc = ["ab", "Ab", "aB", "AB"]`, and you wanted to "merge" it with another letter, e.g. `char = "c"`. Well, I wrote this in a slightly cryptic way: `acc.zip([char] * acc.count).map(&:join)`. But actually, looking again (I did say "can probably be cleaned up"!...), you could also achieve this with `acc.map { |result| result + char }`.

Comment: In other words, this simplifies the last part to: `.inject { |acc, chars| chars.flat_map { |char| acc.map { |result| result + char }} }`

Comment: Came back to this again. I get it :D